# Blender crashes when starting up

Tags: error

I have open blender in all the ways like factory start up and the txt file has a error code 0x00007FF64C7F72E3 and EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. I am using blender 2.82 and i have uninstalled and reinstalled multiple times.

My computer:
i3-7350k
8gb 
gt 1030

Comment: Hello :). Until you find a solution, you can try [Blender 2.81](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.81/) or [2.83 Alpha](https://builder.blender.org/download/).

Comment: I have figured out why i didnt work. I didnt have my graphics card plugged into a monitor